# can nextjs server component loading be deferred?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

currently doing some development on a personal project that can potentially become SaaS application. The application currently uses firebase authentication on the frontend using nextJs 13+. I have all the required component protected.

The issue is, I've written my backend in go and I only want my API endpoints to be accessible to logged in users. I am aware that there is a SDK available to check if a user is authenticated by just passing the uid or token to the backend.But my fetches are async on server components, by the time onAuthStateChanged is updated by firebase, nextjs has already fetched the HTML with data from the server meaning the internal user state is null when the fetch is initial called .

flow: layout.tsx component loads -> fetch in page.tsx -> loading state : true -> onAuthStateChanged (user is auth and able to see dashboard or is rerouted to sign in) -> loading state: false -> displays dashboard from initial load.

There are other ways I can make it work such as using client components. but I rather dive deeper into this.

Ex. code layout:

```
export default function Layout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const setUser = useAuthStore((state) => state.setUser);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (data) => {
            if (data === null) {
                router.push('/');
                return;
            }
            setLoading(false);
            setUser({
                email: data.email
            });
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, [loading]);

    return (
        <htmllang="en">
            <body >
                {loading ? (
                    <Loading/>
                ) : (
                    <>{children}</>
                )}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

page.tsx:

```
async function DashBoard() {
    const data = await getExternalAPI(); // call fetch function
    const user = useAuthStore.getState().user; 

    console.log(user);
    return (<div></div>)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that the dashboard server component will load initially no matter what happened in the layout component since it was in the page.tsx file.
since it is the url path it will load and fetch that page.

the workaround I used was to use the 'page' file as a client component that wraps that server component in a suspense.

TLDR;
the fix is just having the page component ('*/' path) be a client component that imports and render the server component. while having the layout component condition load 'page' like above.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading in Next.js helps improve the initial loading performance of an application by decreasing the amount of JavaScript needed to render a route. It allows you to defer loading of Client Components and imported libraries, and only include them in the client bundle when they're needed.